# How can I connect with other WIFI networks?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid

My laptop catches the signal of other WIFI but it wants an SSID and I don't know his SSID name.

So how can I connect?

Answer (score 3):

If you know the owner of this wifi connection ask him permission and he will provide you with the SSID.